# Thread-safe locking/sychronizing to one permit per resource with multiple resources

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, locking, thread-synchronization

I need to implement thread-safe synchronization to multiple resources, where each resource can be accessed by one thread at a time, but different resources can be accessed concurrently. I have come up with the following code, meant to be used in a try-with-resources statement.

```
public class Gatekeeper implements AutoCloseable
{
   private static final ConcurrentMap<Long, ReentrantLock> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   private final        ReentrantLock                      lock;
   private final        Long                               key;

   public Gatekeeper(Long key)
   {
      this.key = key;
      lock = lockMap.computeIfAbsent(key, (Long absentKey) -> new ReentrantLock(true)); // computeIfAbsent is an atomic operation
      try
      {
         lock.tryLock(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         throw new Something(":(", e);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void close()
   {
      if(lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
      {
         lock.unlock();
      }
   }
}
```

One problem with this code is that no items are ever removed from the lockMap, and I don't know how to do this thread-safe. The following is definitely not thread-safe:

```
@Override
public void close()
{
   if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
   {
      if (lock.getQueueLength() == 1) // todo: getQueueLength is meant for system monitoring purposes only
      {
         lockMap.remove(key); // todo: not thread-safe, queuelength could have changed by now
      }

      lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

the documentation for getQueueLength:

> Returns an estimate of the number of threads waiting to
> acquire this lock.  The value is only an estimate because the number of
> threads may change dynamically while this method traverses
> internal data structures.  This method is designed for use in
> monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization
> control.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Are there different strategies to achieve my goal?

Comment: The bigger problem of this code is that it doesn’t even tell the using code whether it actually owns the lock. When the specified time elapsed, it simply proceeds with the caller thinking that they acquired the lock. The `close()` method is the first to check whether the caller actually owns the lock.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation I came up with the code below, can anyone comment on whether this is a good approach and the code is correct?

```
public class Gatekeeper implements AutoCloseable
{
   private static final ConcurrentMap<Long, ReentrantLock> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   private final        ReentrantLock                      lock;
   private final        Long                               key;

   private static final ConcurrentMap<Long, Integer> claimsPerLock = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   private static final Object                       mutex   = new Object();


   public Gatekeeper(Long key)
   {
      this.key = key;
      
      synchronized (mutex)
      {
         lock = lockMap.computeIfAbsent(key, (Long absentKey) -> new ReentrantLock(true));
         claimsPerLock.compute(key, (k, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : ++oldValue);
      }

      try
      {
         if(!lock.tryLock(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
         {
            throw new SomeException("Timeout occurred while trying to acquire lock");
         }
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         throw new SomeException("Interrupted", e);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void close()
   {
      lock.unlock();

      synchronized (mutex)
      {
         claimsPerLock.compute(key, (k, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 0 : --oldValue);
         if (claimsPerLock.get(key) <= 0)
         {
            lockMap.remove(key);
            claimsPerLock.remove(key);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you can simplify it a lot by using AtomicInteger in claimsPerLock map

Comment: @Mihail I'm not sure that would simplify anything as adding to/removing from the lockMap and claimsMap both need to be synchronized with the same mutex. An AtomicInteger is not necessary in a synchronized block

Comment: This code increments the `claimsPerLock` value even when it fails to acquire the lock. Besides that, there is no point in using `ConcurrentHashMap` when every access to the map happens in a `synchronized` block anyway. In that case, an ordinary `HashMap` would do. And `compute(key, (k, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : ++oldValue)` can be simplified to `merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`.